# creating a column based on missing value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame for which want to create a column that represents missing value patterns in data-frame.For example :

for example for the CSV file,

```
A,B,C,D
1,NaN,NaN,NaN
Nan,2,3,NaN
3,2,2,3
3,2,NaN,3
3,2,1,NaN
```

I want to create a column E,which has value in following way:
If A,B,C,D all are missing E = 4,
If A,B,C,D all are present E = 0,
if A and B are only missing E = 1 of that sort, encoding of E need not be like I mentioned just an indication of pattern.How can I come across this problem in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isnull` in combination with `sum(axis=1)`

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, None, 3, 3, 3],
                  'B':[ None, None, 1, 1, 1]})

df['C'] = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
```